# Where clause in Insert command in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to do something like this

```
insert into tableA(code) select code from tableB where id=tableB.id;
```

I cant insert the code until both id are matched. How do i do this?

Comment: in `where id`, id field is field of tableA ?

Comment: its there in both. so i need to match the id's of both when it inserts the data

Comment: if the id is already in tableA so why you want to insret data on it ? by the way using join you can acomplish this

Comment: tableA(id,code, some other 7-8 columns) 
tableB(id,code,some other 2-3 columns)
Now i need to insert tableB.code into tableA.code matching the id of both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do a join or use `where exists` like

```
insert into tableA(code) 
select tb.code 
from tableB tb 
join tableA on tableA.id = tableB.id;
```

(OR)

```
insert into tableA(code) 
select tb.code 
from tableB tb where exists(select 1 from tableA 
where id = tb.id);
```

Looking at your comment, looks like you rather need a `UPDATE` statement like

```
UPDATE tableA a 
    JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.id 
SET a.code = b.code;
```

Comment: it says ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'code' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Yes, since code column present in both table. BTW, looks you need a update command rather not insert. Look into the edit in answer if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tableA.field1,tableA.field2,......
SELECT tableB.field1,tableB.field2,......
FROM tableB  
JOIN tableA ON tableA.id = tableB.id;
```